# can a method call be chained to the 'set()' built-in? (and why not?)

Tags: python

If I try:

```
mi_list = ['three', 'small', 'words']
mi_set = set(mi_list)
mi_set.remove('small')
print mi_set
```

I get:

```
set(['three', 'words'])
```

which is what I expect. Whereas If I try:

```
mi_list = ['three', 'small', 'words']
mi_set = set(mi_list).remove('small')
print mi_set
```

I get:

```
None
```

Why?

I suspect there's a clue in that if I try to remove an element that isn't present - eg 'big' - an error gets reported:

```
KeyError: 'big'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`set.remove` returns nothing (None).

Your code assigns the return value of `set.remove` to the variable `mi_set`. Therefore, mi_set is None.

Comment: +1 It's a subtle gotcha that I've run into before (although with different methods.)

Comment: +1 it's similar to the list.sort method, it modifies the object but returns None

Answer (score 8):

There is a general convention in python that *methods which cause [side-effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) return None*.  Examples include list.sort, list.append, set.add, set.remove, dict.update, etc.

This is essentially to help you avoid bugs.  Say you had a set called mi_set.  If you could write:

```
mi_set2 = mi_set.remove('small')
```

then a reader might think: "`mi_set2` is different from `mi_set`".  But this would not be the case!  And the confusion might lead to subtle bugs caused by mistakenly sharing data structures.  So by returning `None`, python forces you to remember that methods like those I listed above modify objects, rather than creating new ones.

See also long discussion [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-August/277901.html).  Although note that methods like `sorted()` and `reversed()` have been added since that thread.

[note that list.pop is an exception to this rule, for historical reasons – it lets you use a list like a stack.  And even then, it returns the object removed, rather than the list.]

Comment: Nice answer. sorted and reversed don't change the rationale given here, because they are non-destructive - they don't change the original container.

Comment: Yes, I know sorted() and reversed() don't change the meaning of my post.  I mentioned them because they are a solution to some of the issues people raise in that thread.

Answer (score 1):

The way to go, in your case, would be to use the **difference** member:

```
>>> a = set(["a", "b", "c"])
>>> a = a.difference(["a"])
>>> print a
set(['c', 'b'])
```

The difference is that **remove** acts on the current set (python library object member functions that modify an instance usually return None), whereas **difference** creates and returns a new set.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it return `None`? Because .remove, .add, etc. return `None` :) That's it. They do not support chaining.

`set` is using methods that change it in place. You could create your own version of set that uses chaining, but that can cause some problems:

```
class chain_set(set):
   def chain_add(self, x):
      newself = self.copy()
      newself.add(x)
      return newself

cs = chain_set([1,2,3,4])
cs.chain_add(5)
# chain_set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
cs.chain_add(7)
# chain_set([1, 2, 3, 4, 7])
cs.chain_add(7).chain_add(8)
# chain_set([1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8])
```

The problem is - do you expect `cs` itself to change?

Do you always want to modify the original set (might create some hard to find bugs) or do you want to copy the set every time (might be slow with bigger sets). If you know what behaviour you need and you remember about it - just go ahead with your own set implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the `remove` function returns a value?

Comment: It does return a value, it just happens to be None.

Comment: Not that I have anything against the Socratic method, but I don't think this helps answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

remove modifies the original set without returning anything (or rather, it returns None). This example shows what happens to the original object when you call remove on it:

```
Python 3.0.1 (r301:69561, Feb 13 2009, 20:04:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> s1 = set(lst)
>>> s1
{1, 2, 3}
>>> s2 = s1.remove(2)  # instead of reassigning s1, I save the result of remove to s2
>>> s1
{1, 3}  # *** 2 is not an element in the original set ***
>>> s2  # s2 is not a set at all!
>>>
```

To answer the other part of your question, the exception indicates that remove tried to remove the argument from the set, but couldn't because the argument is not in the set. Conversely, remove returns None to indicate success.